# How to access user typed text inside a text box to make it as a variable? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I want to make a converter GUI, converting Bitcoin to Dollar. I use a textbox to get the user input and a text button to submit. But, when I type number for example 8 to the textbox while test the game and print what is inside the textbox, it printed nothing. Even though I have type 8 to the text box. Thanks for all the answers! Here is the code I use.

```
-- text variable below

local input = script.Parent
local val = input.Text

-- button variable below

local submit = input:FindFirstChild("btcSubmit")


-- player variable below

local gams = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local ld = gams:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
local bitcoin = ld:WaitForChild("Bitcoin").Value
local dollar = ld:WaitForChild("Dollar").Value

-- function

function btcEx()
    val = tonumber(val)
    if val > bitcoin then
        val = tostring(val)
        val = "Sorry, your Bitcoin isn't enough"
        wait(4)
        val = "Input the number of bitcoin you want to exchange here!"
    else
        dollar = val * 8000
        val = tostring()
    end
end

submit.MouseButton1Click:Connect(btcEx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a variable to a value rather than a reference, it remains that value until you change it.

```lua
object.Value = 5
local myValue = object.Value
object.Value = 10
print(myValue) -- Prints 5.
```

This happens because they are not linked and thus changes do not carry over, like these variables below:

```lua
local a = 5
local b = a
a = 10
print(b) -- Prints 5, because b was never changed (but a was).
```

What you want to do is define your button and your value-objects as references, and simply access .Text or .Value when you need to read the value.

```lua
local myButton = button
button.Text = "Howdy!"
print(myButton.Text) -- Prints "Howdy!"
myButton.Text = "Hey there" -- this is the same as button.Text
print(myButton.Text) -- Prints "Hey there"
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and help! I don't know the variable must be declared once more after I type anything to the text box. Thanks again once more!

Comment: Awesome! Would appreciate if you marked it as an Answer :D And if you have more questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Click the tick sign to mark it as the answer right? I'm new so I don't know much :). Mmm, can I have your contact, discord or something else to ask you some question?